# What does it mean to be scratched or scraped?

Tags: translation, meaning, conversation

I tried to translate these sentences from a convo and got a weird translation.

**淺藍不戰爭會被瓜分的.**

Light blue will not be divided by war.

**綠國刮分結束.**

The green country scrapes the end.

**再來是淺藍.**

Again, light blue

Could someone tell me if the translation is correct and what does it mean?

Comment: I think this question heavily lacks context. Are you perhaps talking about a world conquest game, where the countries are highlighted in different colours?

Comment: 淺藍不戰爭會被瓜分的 doesn't really make much sense to me since 戰爭 is a noun and 不 usually does not come before a noun. I'm guessing "Light blue will be divided and respectively owned (by other countries) if it does not go to war"

Comment: YES haha Art of Conquest. I am from the light blue kingdom. Is he threatening to scratch us? @Ben Yang thanks for the confirmation. That's what thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 淺藍(light blue)不(don't)戰爭(war)會(will)被瓜分(be divided)的

戰爭 means war, whereas 戰鬥 is the word to fight. Based on the context it would seem like a typo or a informal slang. The corrected sentence would be 淺藍不**戰鬥**會被瓜分的.

Translated it means: **Light blue will be divided if it does not go to war.**

> 綠(green)國(country)刮分(divide)結束(finish/end)

Translated it means: **Green is now divided.**

I don't think theres this word 刮分. It's likely another typo since they both have the same pinyin `guā`. It should be the one above, 瓜分(divide).

> 再(again)來(come)是(is)淺藍(light blue)

Translated it means: **Next would be light blue.**

**再來是(literally, coming again is)** when used together means "next up is". You can think if it as you are playing a series of chess games, the game master would say **"再來是[Insert name here]"** to announce that the person is coming up next.

To sum up:

**"Light blue will be divided if it does not go to war."**

**"Green is already divided, light blue is next."**